# jQuery get post width to fix on infinite scrolling?

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

James here. This question relates (sort of) to the one I posted a little earlier. I ended up (finally) getting a working script that works with jQuery widths, but it's not working when infinite scrolling loads new posts. The script I'm using is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var cwidth = $(document).width() - 150;
            var pwidth = cwidth - 120;
            var ewidth = (pwidth - 150) / 5;
            var twidth = ewidth - 30;
            var awidth = ewidth - 30;
            $("#container").css("width", cwidth);
            $("#posts").css("width", pwidth);
            $(".entry").css("width", ewidth);
            $(".text").css("width", twidth);
            $(".photo").css("width", ewidth);
            $(".audio embed").css("width", awidth);
        });
        $('p:has(a.tumblr_blog)').remove();
    </script>
    <script src="http://masonry.desandro.com/jquery.masonry.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/FkIlzxaul/infinitescroll.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var $container = $('#posts');
            $container.imagesLoaded(function(){
                $container.masonry({
                    itemSelector: '.entry',
                });
            });

            $container.infinitescroll({
                navSelector  : '#page-nav', 
                nextSelector : '#page-nav a',
                itemSelector : '.entry',
                animate: true,
                loading: {
                    finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
                    img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
                }
            },
            function(newElements) {
                var $newElems = $(newElements).css({ opacity: 0 });
                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                    $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
                    $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
                });
            });
    });
</script>
```

How do I make it so `$(".entry").css("width", ewidth);
                $(".text").css("width", twidth);
                $(".photo").css("width", ewidth);
                $(".audio embed").css("width", awidth);` all get implemented so when the new posts are loaded via infinite scrolling, the posts are the right width? It'd be really helpful if someone could provide a script. Page example: http://jamescharless.tumblr.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your .css jazz into it's own function, and then instantiate it right before the animation for opacity:1.

@Alexander may be right about using .filter, too, on $newElements. You should do a console.log( $newElements ); to see how they have been packaged.

Anyways, **without thinking about optimization or best-practices**, the following should work (use only one $(function(){}); ):

```
var $container = $('#posts');
$container.imagesLoaded(function(){
  $container.masonry({ itemSelector: '.entry' });
});

var cssFix = function()
{
  var cwidth = $(document).width() - 150;
  var pwidth = cwidth - 120;
  var ewidth = (pwidth - 150) / 5;
  var twidth = ewidth - 30;
  var awidth = ewidth - 30;
  $("#container").css("width", cwidth);
  $("#posts").css("width", pwidth);
  $(".entry").css("width", ewidth);
  $(".text").css("width", twidth);
  $(".photo").css("width", ewidth);
  $(".audio embed").css("width", awidth);
}
cssFix();

$container.infinitescroll({
  navSelector  : '#page-nav', 
  nextSelector : '#page-nav a',
  itemSelector : '.entry',
  animate: true,
  loading: {
    finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
    img: 'http://i.imgur.com/6RMhx.gif'
  }
},
function(newElements) {
  var $newElems = $(newElements).css({ opacity: 0 });
  $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
    cssFix();
    $newElems.animate({ opacity: 1 });
    $container.masonry( 'appended', $newElems, true );
  });
});
```

Comment: THIS WORKED! YOU ARE LIKE, JESUS. THANK YOU! :D

Comment: Haha I'm pretty sure Jesus didn't know how to code. :) I think I have a leg-up on him there muwahahhaha. Very glad that this worked for you!

Comment: Do you have a skype by any chance? I'd love to add you on it, if you're active. I'm only 13 but I'm trying really hard to learn jQuery. It'd be a lot easier to have a bud on skype to ask instead of asking here all the time for my unprofessional themes.

Answer (score 0):

I think (without testing) this is what you need to do:

```
$container.infinitescroll({
  ...    
},
function(newElements) {
  var $newElements = $(newElements);
  var cwidth = $(document).width() - 150;
  var pwidth = cwidth - 120;
  var ewidth = (pwidth - 150) / 5;
  var twidth = ewidth - 30;
  var awidth = ewidth - 30;
  $newElements.filter(".entry").css("width", ewidth);
  $newElements.filter(".text").css("width", twidth);
  $newElements.filter(".photo").css("width", ewidth);
  $newElements.filter(".audio embed").css("width", awidth);
  $("#posts").masonry('appended', $newElements);
});
```

Comment: You didn't apply it correctly. You are getting javascript errors. Copy those two lines as they are.

Comment: Actually it is. You just needed to apply the other css. Give it a try now.